# Updating job of workflow manager using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-workflow-manager

I'm trying update the name of a job:

```
updateJob: function (jobId, workArea) {
    let loParameters = new JobUpdateParameters();
    loParameters.jobId = jobId;
    loParameters.name = "Updated";

    let loJobTask = new WMJobTask(poAppVars.urlWFMServer);
    loJobTask.updateJob(loParameters, goHelper.getValueByKeySO("UserName"),
      goHitch(this, function (response) {
        alert('¡¡¡Updated!!!');
      }),
      function (err) {
        console.log('err');
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
```

But I get an error saying:

> Unable to complete operation

Can anyone tell me what's the problem?

Comment: Does the job represented by the jobId exist? This is a typical error for trying to update something in the system that doesn't exist. An easy way to query for your job is: https://<WMServiceURL>/jobs/jobId Also, does your user have the `UpdateProperties` privilege?

Comment: Ask your questions in comments.

Comment: The problem was that the parameters were incomplete